# Where to change list item background color in Eclipse user interface?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, kde-plasma

Please look at this screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJrrT.jpg

I cannot find anywhere under "Colors & Fonts" settings that allows me to change the color of list item background and foreground colors; there is no other KDE application showing black as list background color.

I wish to change the background color to white and foreground color to black, please offer your opinions! Much appreciated!

Comment: thanks Andrew. but my KDE theme is the default oxygen, dark on light..?

Comment: oh, sorry, mis-read.  will delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found.

The color is not specified in Eclipse, instead, it is specified in desktop environment's "GTK Theme".

By default, KDE4 uses gtk-oxygen as GTK theme, the theme has weird colors. So in KDE4 Configura Desktop -> "Application Appearance" I changed GTK theme to Clearlooks. Problem solved.

Answer (score 6):

In **KDE**, just in case someone use **KDE** you don't have to change your theme.
You must change the default Tooltip Background color and Text Color in
System Settings > Application Appearance > Colors > Colors (tab)

Scroll down to Tooltip Text And Tooltip Background

Change the colors, Voila!

Answer (score 0):

Color and Fonts / Tasks / Task List - Category Gradient Bottom?